# error: cannot convert 'const CHAR**' {aka 'const char**'} to 'LPCSTR' {aka 'const char*'} in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, winapi

I have a big chunk of code that I am debugging, and I am stuck trying to figure out why I get the following error when I try to build the project:

> "error: cannot convert 'const CHAR**' {aka 'const char**'} to 'LPCSTR'
> {aka 'const char*'}"

The issue is with the `wsKey` parameter. `SHRegGetValue` is a function defined in the `Shlwapi.h` header, but I don't know how to fix this and I am inexperienced with the Windows API. Please let me know if there is a solution.

```
LPCSTR wsKey[MAX_PATH] = {"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings"};
WCHAR wsValue[MAX_PATH] = L"ProxyEnable";
DWORD dwValue = (DWORD)FALSE;
DWORD dwSize = sizeof(dwValue);
LONG nStatus = SHRegGetValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, wsKey, wsValue, SRRF_RT_DWORD, NULL, &dwValue, &dwSize);
```

Comment: Frankly, the error message tells you what you need to know. Note the difference between `const char**` and `const char*`. Can you see it?  `wsKey` is declared as an array of `LPCSTR`. You want to declare it as `const char[] wsKey = "..."` And surely then you'll have an error on `wsValue` because you are using the ANSI API. You should really be using the Unicode API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line:

```cpp
LPCSTR wsKey[MAX_PATH] = {"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings"};
```

declares `wsKey` to be an array of `MAX_PATH` **character pointers**, the first of which points to the given string literal. If this is *really* what you want, then the second argument to your `SHRegGetValue` call should be that first element: `wsKey[0]`.

However, what is more likely, is that you need `wsKey` to be an array of `MAX_PATH` **characters** – *not* pointers. Like this:

```cpp
const CHAR wsKey[MAX_PATH] = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings"; // Note the removal of the enclosing {...} braces!
```

---

You also have an error with the third parameter to `SHRegGetValue`: this should be a `char` (or `CHAR`) string, *not* a `WCHAR` string (you are mixing up the ANSI and Unicode versions of the call). Declare `wsValue` like this, to use the ANSI version:

```cpp
CHAR wsValue[MAX_PATH] = "ProxyEnable";
```

Alternatively, if you *intend* to use the wide-character (Unicode) version, then you need to change your `wsKey` to a wide-character string. (This seems more likely, given the variable names.)

```cpp
const WCHAR wsKey[MAX_PATH] = L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings";
WCHAR wsValue[MAX_PATH] = L"ProxyEnable";
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't your question answered in your title: `const char**` is not `const char*`. Why you expect that it should work?

I assume it's a copy & paste error. You should write:

```
LPCSTR wsKey = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings";
```

LPCSTR is an alias to `const char *`